# How to do Laplace smoothing in R

Tags: r, naivebayes

How would I code Laplace smoothing in the following code.

```
> model <- naive_bayes(isNeutral ~ ., data = TrainSet, usekernel = T)
```

When I try this, I get this warning message telling me to do this because of 0 probabilities.  I am new to R and I have tried different things but I keep getting errors.

```
 Warning message:
    naive_bayes(): Feature name - zero probabilities are present. Consider Laplace smoothing.
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `?naive_bayes` help page? There's a `laplace` argument described as *value used for Laplace smoothing (additive smoothing). Defaults to 0 (no Laplace smoothing).* Looking through the package documentation there are examples where it is set to `0.5` or `1`.

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to find it through the examples mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

From [`naive_bayes {naivebayes}`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/naivebayes/versions/0.9.7/topics/naive_bayes):

> `laplace` value used for Laplace smoothing (additive smoothing). Defaults to 0 (no Laplace smoothing).